# amp-form with target _blank should redirect after set the header AMP-Redirect-To?

Tags: amp-html

after set the header `AMP-Redirect-To` in a `amp-form` with`target=_blank` got no redirect, what is the correct behaviour?

i could not found anything in the docs about the targets

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#redirecting-after-a-submission

only works with `target=_top`

Comment: The normal behavior when you put `_blank` as a value to `target` is to open a new window or tab, as implied from the Note found on this [page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form#target).

Comment: so, instead of a redirect the value of `AMP-Redirect-To` should open a new tab/window?

Comment: target _blank work with get method, for post you can try on form submit : on="submit-success:AMP.navigateTo(url='http://example.com',target='_blank')"

Comment: I just want to know the correct behaviour for `AMP-Redirect-To` for form submission redirection with a `target=_blank`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use another way, since the "AMP-Redirect-To" behavior doesn't make sense to me.
You could avoid AMP-Redirect-To overall and make sure that the file the form is calling sends the right CORS header. Since AMP-Redirect-To normally gives you only one option, and that is the file you're pointing it to, that might not be your best choice.